# Intersection points of straight line segment with Voronoi diagram

Tags: convex-geometry

Hi,

I need to find the x,y points of intersection of a vertical line with the edges of the Voronoi cells it goes through in a defined, rectangular plane region with a given Voronoi tesselation. Is there any computationally efficient method to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper by Chazelle and Liu,

> "Lower bounds for intersection searching and fractional cascading in higher dimension."
>   2001.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=380818))

shows that for planar convex subdivisions, the answer is *Yes*, there is a computationally
efficient method **if** you allow quadratic storage, but *No* if you insist on subquadratic
storage:

---

[image: Chazelle]

---

Your one hope is that, because a Voronoi diagram is a special convex subdivision, this result
can be improved by exploiting its Voronoi-ness.

Answer (score 1):

The question seem to be nearly as hard as finding Voronoi diagram.

In other words, you have a collection of functions 
of the form 
$$f_i(t)=t^2+a_i{\cdot}t+b_i$$
and you need to find the maximal interval $[c_i,d_i]$ 
where 
$$f_i=\min_{j}\{f_j\}.$$

Yo will get the same answer, if instead of $f_i$, 
you use the functions 
$$h_i(t)=a_i{\cdot}t+b_i=f_i(t)-t^2$$
which are linear. 
I.e., your problem is equivalent to the classical problem in linear programming --- choose you favorite method.